# kafka connect behavior on no consumers in group

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a problem that I'm not sure how to understand it, more than actually fix it.
I tried some support here but I think I was wrong and this might be related to the actual connectors themselves and not my infrastructure setup
https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/discussions/6418

Not sure if relevant but I am using the JDBC Sink connector from confluent.
Once I set it up everything seems to work fine but every one in a while all my consumers will leave the group and basically data will not longer be sink.

I can see in the log:

```
[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-bde-objects-0, groupId=connect-sink-jdbc-bde-objects] Member connector-consumer-sink-jdbc-bde-objects-0-3333ce54-ddc4-41ad-878e-cc74f36e8ffd sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator abc-strimzi-kafka-kafka-0.abc-strimzi-kafka-kafka-brokers.insight-data-flow-nightly.svc:9093 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

The message is relatively clear, the data cannot be processed in time and the connector stops working.
Now the part I don't like, or is strange to me is that I would expect the connector to go into an error status and not stay as if nothing bad was happening.
Second even if this happens I would like to sort of get an alert but I can't distinguish this from normal rebalancing activities in the consumer group.

Does anyone have experience with this problem or can point me if there is any special configuration I should look out for at the kafka level that could be used to manage this?
I can't for sure define the pool size and the pool interval but somehow the values might not always be correct and when they stop being correct I would like to see that there is some sort of error and not that the lag simply keeps grown and no messages are consumed.

Thanks for any feedback and best regards

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? Also faced the same problem.

Comment: I think there is not a solution and this is really per design. Basically the threads go into error mode by not being able to process all the records in the times defined. once you reach all timeouts it simple fails for the thread and that's what happens